# Best practice management of conda, pip, system, and personal software

Tags: python, pip, conda, environment, package-managers

In my work I need a mix of C++, Fortran and Python codes to interact, in the latter case mainly via Cython and SWIG. They are a mix of widely-used libraries (typically available via some package management system), ones specific to my field but not written by me (mostly not packaged beyond source tarballs), and ones for which I'm the developer.

For a long time we've been able to get by without worrying too much about Python 3, and so I operated a `~/local` install area with a mix of the compiled and Python2-based software in the usual `bin`, `lib`, `lib/python2.*/site-packages`, etc. structure, and with the relevant subdir paths included in my `.bashrc` `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `PYTHONPATH` environment variables. But in particular with the rise of Python 3 for machine learning, and an increase in incompatible ML packages, I've had to start operating virtualenv directories for some projects. This, and also the switch of system tools like `meld` to Python 3, mean that my single, global, Python 2 environment isn't fit for purpose anymore.

At the same time, I've become aware that conda and condaforge are now being pushed for a lot of relevant software. So there's now going to be system packages and Python versions, potentially conda environments (for specific Pythons), pip packages (in virtualenvs or not), and then my personal builds. This is quite a lot to operate consistently, and there doesn't seem to be much information out there about best-practice, especially when sharing some code between multiple projects, and mixing in non-Python libraries with these Python-focused tools. Installing a whole chain of manual dependencies in an independent conda or virtualenv environment for each project would be very difficult to manage and wasteful in terms of duplication of large libraries, but on the other hand there seems to be at least a need for separate Python 2/3 environments, perhaps with more project-specific virtualenvs within them.

So, scene set -- apologies for the length, but it's intrinsically complex. Is anyone else wrestling with this problem, and is there an emerging standard or best-practice way to manage the mix of system, conda, pip, and manual package dependencies for development of many projects, without undue duplication?

PS. I appreciate answers may be opinion-based to some extent, although good ones will evidence and justify their recommendations. On the other hand, it's definitely about software development rather than just software management. So I hope it's an appropriate question for SO, since I don't see a better fit within the SX network.

Comment: have a feeling this might get closed as opinion based, but I just use virtualenvs and try not to worry about the wasted space.  I set `PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV` so that I don't accidentally install any packages outside a venv.  larger venvs are ~0.5GB, but I only tend to have a handful so don't worry much (e.g. one for each major project, a general purpose one, a throw-away one) major projects also get a `requirements.txt` file so things can mostly be installed again relatively easily.  not sure if that helps, but think this sort of question is best answered by blogs